# Difference between "aim" and "purpose"

Tags: differences, language-formation

The explanation in the dictionary of an "**aim**" is

> The aim of something that you do is the purpose for which you do it or the result that it is intended to achieve.

and the explanation of a "**purpose**" is

> The purpose of something is the reason for which it is made or done.

So are there any differences between "aim" and "purpose"?

And which word should I fill in the blank? "But for the _____of communication, we dress in clothes of different colors."

Comment: For all intents and purposes, "for the purpose of" is a fixed phrase. "For the aim of" is unheard of. As is always the case with fixed phrases, meaning never really enters the building. It is as it is. You don't need to think about or even know the meaning of *aim* or *purpose* to know which one to pick.

Answer (score 3):

In Koine Greek, both would be [telos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telos_%28philosophy%29), but in modern English, the weight of meanings would tend to prefer purpose here.

Purpose is strictly a noun - It tends to adhere mostly to the reason behind an action or thing.  e.g. The purpose of X is to Y.

Aim, on the other hand, can be both a noun and a verb.  Typically the first thought with aim is to point, as in a gun.  In other words, I'd aim my weapon at the target.  And, as a verbal noun, the aim of an organization can be that thing on which they are focused.  But, it is usually less of a "reason" than a direction.

For that reason, since you are taking about the reason for communication rather than its direction, I would use "purpose".

And, as the RedDwight suggests, "for the purposes of" is pretty much idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

Both convey the same meaning. If at all, the distinction between them is very thin.

I'd use '*purpose*' for your blank.

> But for the *purpose* of communication, we dress in clothes of different colors.

I wouldn't use 'aim' in situations like this. It sounds odd.